# Tenses in the clause "was about to do"

Tags: grammar, tenses, auxiliary-verbs

There are two verbs in the clause "was about to do", and I think I have established that "was" is an auxiliary verb, but I am unsure of what the verb "do" is. It is not a present participle, but I don't know how to refer to it.

How would you describe the tense of these verbs?

My current thinking is that it may be the periphrastic past tense.

Comment: _(To) do_ is an infinitive.

Comment: _Was about to do_ is not a clause. It's part of a verb phrase, and while *`X` is about to `V`* does mean that `X` will soon `V`, it's not future tense. _Was_ is past tense, and _to do_ is, as @JanusBahsJacquet points out, an infinitive, and infinitives don't have any tense. There are lots more ways to express various shades of futurity, but they're not tenses; they're just idioms and constructions, like everything else. English only has two tenses, past and present; there is no future tense.

Answer (score 3):

***Do*** here is not tensed; it is the *plain form* of the verb, used as an *infinitive*. The plain form is the only verb form that can be used after what some people refer to as *infinitival to* as shown below:

- To errs is human *
- To erring is human *
- To erred is human *

A good test to see if a verb form is actually in the plain form is to substitute it with the verb ***BE***. If it turns out as ***am/are/is*** then it's present tense, if it turns out as *be* it's the plain form.

The ***was*** here is past tense (sometimes referred to as the *preterite*). Those linguists who are mainly concerned with theoretical linguistics, use the word *tense* to mean very specifically that the verb in question is inflected (for time reference, or modality, or backshift). They will tend to say things like "there are only two tenses in English". The verb form ***was*** here is the only verb that is marked for primary tense in this way.

However, 'tense' for many other people who work with language refers to whole verbal catenations. These are given names such as the *future simple*, *past perfect* or *going to future* and so forth. These phrases are useful for talking about the characteristic forms used to talk about the way people describe and perceive events and situations in time. If your question is about this issue, then I don't believe that there is a specialised term for the construction you are talking about. Some people would regard ***to be about to (x)*** as an idiomatic expression, and some people might even argue that it is a phrasal verb. The individual parts of speech are: ***was*** - past tense auxiliary verb; ***about*** - preposition; infinitival ***to*** ( - what part of speech ***to*** is, turns out to be a bit contentious): ***do*** - infinitive/plain form.

Comment: Is *about* really a preposition here?  It seems more like an adverb or even adjective to me. Compare it with *X was likely to do Y*, which appears to be a syntactically identical construction, in which *likely* is quite clearly not a preposition.

Comment: “If it turns out as is then it's present tense, if it turns out as be it's the infinitive” — or the imperative … or the present subjunctive. Far be it for me to be facetious, lest I be seen as negative of mind; but the test is unfortunately not quite so simple as that. :-)

Comment: @Anonym The word is obviously the preposition _about_, but I agree that it’s not really functioning very prepositionally here. There are oodles of constructions with `Adjective` + _to_-infinitive, and I agree that’s a better template to understand _about to_ under, as well. It also means we don’t have to worry about whether the infinitive is the object of _about_ (and if so, why a full _to_-infinitive is suddenly allowed to act as the object of a preposition, which they aren’t normally, except with _save_, _except_, and _but_, all of which share the same meaning).

Comment: It also depends on whether you use ‘plain form’ to mean the morphological _form_ of the verb or the syntactical _function_ of the verb. The ‘plain form’ is arguably just the morphophonetic sequence of sounds/letters that is used for various purposes and tenses and forms and functions.

Comment: @Anonym, Janus That partly depends on what your view on prepositions is. I'm firmly in the CaGEL camp here, so whether it's followed by a noun/clause/nothing doesn't count. I would definitely rule out it's being an adverb. Your point about being similar to *likely to* is a good one and made me think. We expect adjectives to be modifiable by adverbs, whereas prepositions very seldom are. Compare 'I'm very likely to go' and 'I'm very about to go'. The latter is definitely wrong, indicating that *about* is not an adjective - or an adverb.

Comment: @Anonym, Janus, I wouldn't take the test above as decisive, though. There's one more piece of evidence, which is that prepositions are typically modifiable by the word ***right***: ***go right on, sit right down, right on the edge*** etc. Compare ***I'm right likely to leave*** with ***I'm right about to leave***. The former isn't viable, but the latter's fine. This is perhaps much stronger evidence than the above - though again not fool-proof! :) –